# Must I use Android X?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I'm coding an Android App and I'm using

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

I try to connect Firebase but it say use Android X. Must I use it? I'm using 3rd party libraries, is it a problem on Android X and if I must use Android X how can I do it safetly?

> Edit:

My build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Comment: Yes, you must use AndroidX

Comment: You can migrate to androidx very easily. Check this out https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: what 3rd party libraries are you using. if they are using the old android.support libraries, then you are out of luck.

Comment: I added my project's build.gradle to my question @AngelKoh

Comment: @FatalError you will have issues (wait for the libraries to be updated, or you have to find another equivalent that uses androidx). Just check the Issues page of each library individually to see if they have a solution for it or not, e.g. for the otpview ->  https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview/issues/60

Comment: @FatalError alternatively, you can try using an older version of firebase that still uses the android.support as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you must use androidX

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your gradle.properties file:

**android.useAndroidX=true**
The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.
With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your **gradle.properties file**:

**android.useAndroidX=true**
The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.
**android.enableJetifier=true**

Answer (score 0):

No, Its an option but if you want to use new features and new libraries and also jetpack than you must use android x.

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack components are part of the AndroidX library.

If you want to use Jetpack components, you must use Androidx.

For setup Androidx or migrate you can follow this link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

There are following list of Android Jetpack Component

[image: Android Jetpack Component]