# Android - SearchView setFilters and color of the text

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to create a SearchView and programatically change textcolor and add filters e.g. max length.

```
SearchView search = findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
TextView textView = search.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    textView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15)});
```

This way it says **Cannot resolve symbol 'search_src_text'**

Then I tried:

```
SearchView search = findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
int id = search.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView textView = search.findViewById(id);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        textView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15)});
```

In this case there is No error, but only warning, that **Use of getIdentifier is discouraged**

My Searchview in xml:

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/searchfield"
     />
```

Is there any other way to do the same thing with SearchView without any warnings and errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to replace the SearchView with `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` and use

```
val searchView: SearchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView1)
val textView: TextView = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
```

Here is some information on [Why to use androidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959251/must-i-use-android-x)

Sample gradle update

```
implementation ("androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0")
implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

val navVersion = "2.7.6"

implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
// navigation
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion")
```

Comment: I had it before as androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView, and there was same issue with not recognizing search_src_text

Comment: maybe you have not enabled androidX works for me

Comment: not sure why, androidX is enabled. For now I leave it as getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text". This way it works, I'll ignore the warning

Comment: @Darksymphony i have updated my gradle please compare your versions

Comment: yes my gradle is up to date. Now I tried to use androidx.appcompat again and for some reason seems working: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView search = findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        TextView textView = search.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

Comment: @Darksymphony that's great, love it if you can accept the answer for others to see